# Expectation of dropout

Tags: derivatives, expected-value

I am new to expectation and could definitely use some resources on how to use them with respect to deep learning/reinforcement learning. Upon reading .an article on the math behind dropout we come to an expectation of a derivative. I understand how we achieve the derivative but not the expectation, I am looking for some clarity on their approach and possible resources on the matter.

Given:
$$
\frac{\partial E_D}{\partial w_i} = \frac12 (t - \sum_{i=1}^n \delta_iw_iI_i)^2 = -t\delta_iI_i + w_i\delta_i^2I_i^2 + \sum_{j=1,j\ne i}^n\delta_i\delta_jI_iI_jw_i
$$

We want to take the expectation of the gradient which is described as:

$$
\Bbb{E}\left[\frac{\partial E_D}{\partial w_i}\right]
 = -tp_iI_i + w_ip^2_iI_i^2 + w_iVar(\delta_i)I_i^2+\sum_{j=1,j\ne i}^n w_jp_ip_jI_iI_j
$$

Here is the article for reference, I am talking about figure (6) https://towardsdatascience.com/simplified-math-behind-dropout-in-deep-learning-6d50f3f47275

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\delta_i$ is by definition Bernoulli($p_i$) and independent across $i$. So, using linearity of expectation $(E[X+Y]=E[X]+E[Y])$:

1) $E[\delta_i]=p_i$,

2) $E[\delta_i^2] = \mbox{Var}(\delta_i^2)+E[\delta_i]^2 = p_i(1-p_i)+p_i^2,$

3) $E[\delta_i\delta_j]=E[\delta_i]E[\delta_j]=p_ip_j$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am still a bit confused. Can you further clarify the meaning of step 2, where does the variance come from (I assume it is due to the power of two but am not very clear). And what is the meaning of variable p?

Comment: @JacobB This is more of a massaging trick to coax out the $p_i^2$ necessary to match the gradient piece with $E_N$ ((5) of the linked article). Otherwise, 2 is just the definition of variance if you move $E[\delta_i]^2$ to the left side.

Comment: $p_i$ is the dropout probability for neuron $i$, which could potentially differ across layers or neurons (although most of the time people just use  one probability $p_i=p$ across everything).

Comment: I see, thank you for the clarification. I am able to understand the variable $p$ and coaxing out the $p^2_i$ but I am not clear on what you mean by 2 is the definition of the variance if $E[\delta_i]^2$ is moved to the left side.

Comment: Ahh this video has cleared up some of my confusion https://www.khanacademy.org/math/statistics-probability/random-variables-stats-library/binomial-mean-standard-dev-formulas/v/bernoulli-distribution-mean-and-variance-formulas. Sorry for the dumb question and thank you for your help.